# UIAlertView crashes when added to app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uialertview, iboutlet

I am trying to impliment a basic `UIAlertView` into my app (I am using storyboard). But when I run my app, it goes to the debugger screen after stalling at the app's loading screen.

my .h:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface MindTripAnim :UIViewController {   
      IBOutlet UIImageView *animation;
    }

    - (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender;

    @end
```

and my .m:

```
#import "MindTripAnim.h"
@interface MindTripAnim ()
@end

@implementation MindTripAnim

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"trips1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"trips2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"trips3.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"trips4.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"trips5.png"],                          
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"trips6.png"],nil];
   [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:0];    
   animation.animationDuration = 0.65; 
   [animation startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)showMessage:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!" message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}
@end
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or why the app keeps stalling at the loading screen, please help!

I found this in the debugger

> 2012-12-01 19:39:03.428 MindTrip[3327:11303] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught        exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key Alert.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1c9a012 0x10d7e7e 0x1d22fb1 0xb84711 0xb05ec8 0xb059b7 0xb30428 0x23c0cc 0x10eb663 0x1c9545a 0x23abcf
>   0xffe37 0x100418 0x100648 0x100882 0x4fa25 0x4fdbf 0x4ff55 0x58f67
>   0x1cfcc 0x1dfab 0x2f315 0x3024b 0x21cf8 0x1bf5df9 0x1bf5ad0 0x1c0fbf5
>   0x1c0f962 0x1c40bb6 0x1c3ff44 0x1c3fe1b 0x1d7da 0x1f65c 0x2a4d 0x2975)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)

Comment: Are you ever calling your method `showMessage:`?

Comment: can you paste in what your debugger says

Comment: that method is linked to an info button, I followed this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/

Comment: What exactly do you see on your screen when you launch your app? A black screen? A white screen?

Comment: screenshot http://postimage.org/image/5fyeoibjl/, It used to stall at the loading screen, now it just shuts down

Comment: I think your best bet is to rerun without the animation images.  Try wrapping all that stuff in viewDidLoad in /* */.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no dice http://postimage.org/image/xulxu250r/                               I'm starting to think it has to do with the @ end at the beginning

Comment: Do you know if your application is going into any of your functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have added `alert`(or a pointer to some view called `alert`) in your storyboard but the same is not added to the class code. If you are displaying the alert view programmatically, you can remove it from the storyboard.