# iOS: How to cleanly delete UIButton outlet?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, iboutlet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIAlertView crashes when added to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665396/uialertview-crashes-when-added-to-app)

I recently tried to delete a UIButton outlet called `myButton`, but I'm thinking I must have missed something because I now get the following error:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myButton

If I grep the entire project, there are **no remaining references** to myButton, so I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

How does one get rid of this exception?

Comment: code plz. ?? try [myButton removeFromSuperView]

Comment: The problem is not in code, it's in Interface Builder.

Comment: Remove it from the xib. This error is because of that.

Comment: If you believe you have removed all connections and the button from the xib, then try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the xib file as as an xml file ( test editor ) and delete it from there, or delete the xib file and re-create the components

Comment: This did the trick. Now I'm just wondering why cross-project find didn't work when finding within the xml file did...

Comment: This is working because you removed the outlet from the File's Owner from the xml, there's no need to edit the XML directly and I would advice against it. Understand what's going on rather than just deleting an element with the name "myButton" in it.

Comment: @mkral I had the same situation, I knew it, that's why I told. I have renamed an outlet - or unlinket not sure, but at .h file wasn't and it gives me compiler error. I have digged the more hours to see: it is only in xib file: nowhere elese. So I had to delete the element from xib, or remade the ui definition ( xib file) with Inteface Builder

Answer (score 3):

You're having this error message, because you removed the IBOutlet from the controller, but the link in Interface Builder is still there.

To resolve that, go to the specified xib under Interface Builder, right click on "File's Owner" and remove links with a warning icon.

[image: File's Owner right click]

Comment: Note that you can't select "File's Owner" in the Utilities inspector to do this.  You have to option-click it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably still have it connected to nothing in the .xib

Make sure that your Variable/property is deleted from the header and in interface builder make sure under your connections tab that you don't have connections around to items that are not there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

try right-clicking the button on your storyboard and clicking x in the corner of your old outlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XIBs or Storyboards, I suggest you take a look at your views in there and try to find the one that is trying to attach an outlet to `myButton`. Delete the connection from Interface Builder and you should be good to go.