# Tab Bar Controller in the second screen

Tags: ios, xcode, controller, tabbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIAlertView crashes when added to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665396/uialertview-crashes-when-added-to-app)

I'm new at objective-C and Xcode. In my app the first screen is a view controller and a button on it. I want to show tab bar when I press that button, so tab bar to be the second screen.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

`appdelegate.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstViewController *viewController1;
```

`appdelegate.m`

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     self.viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
     self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController1;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES; }
```

In my `FirsViewController.m` there is event for button click:

```
 -(IBAction) showMainView:(id) sender{  
     ViewController *mainViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"
                                                                           bundle:nil];
     [self.view addSubview:mainViewController.view];
     mainViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"                          
                                                           bundle:nil];
     [self.view addSubview:mainViewController.view];
```

ViewController is a xib with tab bar.

In the second xib file in IB I chose UIApplication class for the "File's owner" and for an AppDelegate - appdelegate class. And then I joined file's owner with the app delegate.

When I run my app and click on the button on my first view, app crashes with the following error:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x744f0f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.'`

Could you tell me how can I overcome this problem? May be after clicking button I should reassign tabbarController to be the `rootViewController`?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating `mainViewController` twice? Your code looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like, you have set up something in xib named `delegate` which is not connected properly to the class file(ViewController). Check if your xib is showing some warning message and remove that or fix that issue.

Comment: There are no warnings in my project at all. If I delete link between File's owner(UIApplication) and AppDelegate, my app crash with another exception:"[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'"

Comment: @BIB, So there is nothing named `delegate` in your xib which is not defined in viewcontroller class?